# Detect facebook-like / message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am haunted by the following question.

Want to make a `mini-homepage`, i would like to ask visitors to `facebook-like` my page, after they signed up to my newsletter.

Once they liked my page i want to send them an email thanking them for the facebook-like.

**Question**:

Is there a way i can detect if a certain visitor on my page has liked my page and connect this to his/her session / email address (might be different then fb email address)?

Comment: facebook-like 'my page', does it mean that your page is an external website ?

Comment: yes correct, external website

Answer (score 1):

It's in the Facebook documentation:

> How do I know when a user clicks a Like button?
>
> If you are using the XFBML version of the button, you can subscribe to
>   the 'edge.create' event through FB.Event.subscribe.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/